# MenuItem's toString method returns empty String, why?

Tags: java, android, android-menu

Here's my code:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.tracking_menu, menu);

        myLocationMenuItem = menu.getItem(0);

        if (myLocationMenuItem == null) {
            Log.i("MenuItemLogging", "instance is:  null");
        } else {
            Log.i("MenuItemLogging", "instance is not null: " + myLocationMenuItem.toString());
        }
    }
```

Here's the log:

> 03-24 10:19:06.215: I/MenuItemLogging(8519): instance is not null:

And there **aren't any String for the myLocationMenuItem.toString()**'s return value.

The MenuItem class have the same toString as Object:

```
public String toString() {
        return getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
    }
```

But it returns empty String.

**How is that possible?**

Comment: is it just curiosity about the toString ?

Comment: It is "dont understanding" about the toString, How could it return empty String?

Comment: you are probably looking to the wrong class. Where did you find that implementation?

Comment: It's ctrl+click on the method. Simply open's the implementation.

Comment: no it is not. `MenuItem` is an interface. You need its real implementation. Look for `MenuItemImpl`

Comment: what do you mean by *So*?

Comment: Yes, add this as an answer pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MenuItem` is an interface. If you try to get the implementation of `myLocationMenuItem.toString()` you will get the toString() implementation of `Object`. What you want is the implementation of toString() of a class that implements `MenuItem` (`MenuItemImpl`), which is

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return mTitle != null ? mTitle.toString() : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already looked at the following page, this could be of some use to you:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html